# Cannot find android sdk in eclipse

Tags: android, api, sdk, eclipse-adt

How to get android sdk 5.0 api 21 - not available in eclipse android sdk manager
Please tell me the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the SDK Manager to dowload all the required SDKs (the ones listed in the [DashBoard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone)).

Comment: My SDK Manager does not have all the required SDKs. I already know that.

Comment: I-M-P-O-S-S-I-B-L-E. Check out the "obsolete" checkmark as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the above problem do the below steps,

1.Open Android SDK Manager

2.Wait for a while it will take little time to fetch all the packages details

3.Choose the required packages(API 21) and click on Install packages button

4.It will take time i.e. upto your internet connection.

5.When it complete enjoy your latest features what you are downloaded or updated.

Hope this will be helpful...Thanks

Comment: Anyway, I found out a way to get API 21 without using SDK manager or eclipse.

Comment: @PrivateTrickor Sounds good ,any way you found the solution that's great..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK manager checking updates properly then update your build-tools. Finally you will see the API 21.

If not works then restart your Eclipse.